# Dynamic select from database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a small question.

I'm using a PDO for my database querys. Now I want to access a single value of one row in a table.

This is my code:

```
public function select_single_value_login_member($field_name, $key)
{
    $select_field = "SELECT {$field_name} FROM DB#######.login_member WHERE id_member = '$key'";

    $value = $this->db_link->query($select_field)->fetchObject()->value;

    // Zurückgeben
    return $value;
}
```

`this->db_link` is a global variable, which contains the db-connection via PDO.

Now I want to call this method in another file:

```
$admin = $db->select_single_value_login_member('admin', $key);
```

My problem is now, that the value `$admin` is empty.

Is there any code, which is missing or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are looking for the value of property `value`, you probably want the value of the `$field_name` property.

So your code would be something like:

```
 ...
 $value = $this->db_link->query($select_field)->fetchObject()->{$field_name};
 //                                                       here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**However**, note that you should use a prepared statement for the `$key` value and check the `$field_name` against a whitelist of allowed column names to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you :D